# How to import react-pdf-table into react-pdf

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, react-pdf

I am referring to [this](https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf) version of react-pdf, not the other one.

When I run the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf.git
cd react-pdf
npm install "@david.kucsai/react-pdf-table"
```

Then add a Table component to the pageWrap example and run `yarn example -- pageWrap`, I naturally run into the `ReferenceError: Table is not defined` error.

*However*, every import statement I have tried, like

1. `import '@david.kucsai/react-pdf-table';`
2. `import Table from '@david.kucsai/react-pdf-table';`
3. `import {Table} from '@david.kucsai/react-pdf-table';`

has failed with a `code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'` error.

I am puzzled as to how one is supposed to import this package.

Comment: @Alex the bolding was pointless in the first case and wrong in the second, and there were several actual problems you ignored

Comment: Nvm you mean the enumeration?